# Query fields in a MongoDB Collection.

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to query specific fields in a mongodb collection. Here is my code and output:

```
    Mongo m = new Mongo();
    DB db = m.getDB( "mydb" );
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("student") ;


    // adding data 
    BasicDBObject moz = new BasicDBObject();
    moz.put("Name", "Mozammil");
    coll.insert(moz);



    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();


    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());

    }
```

This returns the following:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4f5a4477c5e80f71ece56797"} , "Name" : "Mozammil"}
```

However, i want only the Name part. Googling around, this should do the job.

```
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find({}, {'Name':1});


    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

But it is not working. Help please?

Comment: You should instead be modifying your print.  Instead of just dumping the whole row from `cursor.next()` you should put that in a `JSONObject` and then only print the fields you want using the JSONObject methods

Comment: Actually, there is another issue with the query itself. http://d.pr/YVXu

Comment: I meant just using the first find() and then parsing out only the name field in your print loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use get on the returned document by the cursor to get the field you are looking for. Like this:

```
System.out.println(cursor.next().get("key"));
```

Comment: This will probably transfer the entire document to the client which can be expensive depending on the documents size.

Comment: how would one go about printing multiple keys from the same object using this method?

Answer (score 9):

I know you already accepted an answer, but it isn't exactly what you were asking for.

Here is some working code:

```
// get Mongo set up...
Mongo m = new Mongo();
DB db = m.getDB( "test" );
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("test");

// insert a test record
coll.insert(new BasicDBObject("Name","Wes").append("x", "to have a second field"));

// create an empty query
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); 
// configure fields to be returned (true/1 or false/0 will work)
// YOU MUST EXPLICITLY CONFIGURE _id TO NOT SHOW
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("Name",true).append("_id",false);

// do a query without specifying fields (and print results)
DBCursor curs = coll.find(query);
while(curs.hasNext()) {
   DBObject o = curs.next();
   System.out.println(o.toString());
}

// do a query specifying the fields (and print results)
curs = coll.find(query, fields);
while(curs.hasNext()) {
   DBObject o = curs.next();
   System.out.println(o.toString());
}
```

The first query outputs:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4f5a6c1603647d34f921f967"} , "Name" : "Wes" , "x" : "to have a second field"}
```

And the second query outputs:

```
{ "Name" : "Wes"}
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [DBCollection.find](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.2/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29)

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(); // because you have no conditions
BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("Name",1);
coll.find(query, fields);
```

Comment: Oh, and add a comma instead of a colon. :(

Comment: Sorry it does not work. It still outputs { "_id" : { "$oid" : "4f5a39b0c5e8bf8284432cb4"} , "Name" : "Mozammil"}

Comment: This did the trick :  System.out.println(cursor.next().get("Name"));

Comment: the syntax I gave you will just give the requested fields and the _id (except ofc for the mongo shell version ':' - not valid java). The cursor.next().get(key) retrieves the entire object and you're then manually extracting.

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.find().projection(Projections.include("Name"))
```

this worked such well!!!

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: OK。Maybe you are right,but at first i think if i supply more information about it, then the answer is meaningless.Knowledge is important,but a heart to explore even more valuable。

Answer (score 0):

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();

BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();
fields.put("name", 1);

DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, fields);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To get all nested keys:

```
    public static ArrayList<String> getKeys(Document it1) throws JSONException {

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> resultTemp;
        String temp;
        Document doc;
        JSONArray jsa;

        int len, i;
        System.out.println(it1);
        String js = it1.toJson();
        JSONObject js1 = new JSONObject(js);

        Iterator<String> keys = js1.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            if (key.equals("_id")) {
                result.add(key);
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(key);

            temp = js1.get(key).toString();
            if (temp.contains(":")) {
                jsa = new JSONArray(temp);
                len = jsa.length();
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jsa.getJSONObject(i);
                    doc = Document.parse(object.toString());
                    System.out.println(doc);
                    resultTemp = getKeys(doc);
                    for (String keyTemp : resultTemp) {
                        if (!result.contains(key + "." + keyTemp))
                            result.add(key + "." + keyTemp);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                result.add(key);
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
   {"$project":{"arrayofkeyvalue":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}},
   {"$unwind":"$arrayofkeyvalue"},
   {"$group":{"_id":null,"columns":{"$addToSet":"$arrayofkeyvalue.k"}}}
 ])
```

Use the above query it will give you all the fields of a document. In this you will get nested field also.