# Mongodb Java - How to return all fields of a collection

Tags: java, mongodb

With the driver Java Mongodb, I am looking for a way to return all fields of one collection.For example, I have a collection "people", how can I get all fields, I want output： 'id','name','city'...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query fields in a MongoDB Collection.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639260/query-fields-in-a-mongodb-collection)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am trying to query all field name of a collection instead of specific fields.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot, I have finally got the answer.

```
DBCursor cur = db.getCollection("people").find();
DBObject dbo = cur.next();
Set<String> s = dbo.keySet();
```

Answer (score 1):

From [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/java/query/):

To return all documents in a collection, call the `find` method without a criteria document. For example, the following operation queries for all documents in the restaurants collection.

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("restaurants").find();
```

Iterate the results and apply a block to each resulting document.

```
 iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final Document document) {
            System.out.println(document);
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to decide on the number of samples that would make sense to you but this would pull the last 10 submissions.

```
Document nat = new Document().append("$natural",-1);
    FindIterable<Document> theLastDocumentSubmitted = collection.find().limit(10).sort(nat);

    ArrayList<String>fieldkeys = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (Document doc : theLastDocumentSubmitted) {
        Set<String> keys = doc.keySet();
        Iterator iterator = keys.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            String value = (String) doc.get(key).toString();
            if(!fieldkeys.contains(key)) {
                fieldkeys.add(key);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("fieldkeys" + fieldkeys.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

- Below code will return all fields from given collection.

  ```
   MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("collection_name");
                      AggregateIterable<Document> output = mongoCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                              new Document("$project", Document("arrayofkeyvalue", new Document("$objectToArray", "$$ROOT"))),
                              new Document("$unwind", "$arrayofkeyvalue"),
                              new Document("$group", new Document("_id", null).append("allkeys", new Document("$addToSet", "$arrayofkeyvalue.k")))
                      ));
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Below code will return all fields of people collection :

db.people.find()

Comment: This line returns a DBCursor object, then what should I do next? Use a method in DBCursor class?